# Compile with -m32 option in python on 64bit Ubuntu(14.04)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, ctypes

I'm trying to wrap 32bit .so files with python's 'ctypes' module

If I load .so files in python, it makes errors

```
OSError: ./test.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

To solve this problem, I searched many websites and found two solutions

First one is using configure options, CFLGAS and LDFLAGS. But, it was too difficult and brief for me to follow it.

Second one is to install python2.7:i386. Surely, it works, but it deletes original version of python, and it cannot compile 64bit programs.

Can you suggest other solutions or explain how to deal with ./configure in detail?